# Stripe webhooks events order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, stripe-payments

I'm currently building a node application that's using Stripe for payments. I've got webhooks setup and working as I want to create subscribers in my application but require the response from the stripe webhooks to store the data received for different events in different collections in my mongo db.

The issue I'm having is that the order of events sent by Stripe is not always in the same order and in order to create relationships between documents/collections I require that the event handlers are triggered in the following order:

1. customer.created
2. customer.card.created (relates to customer)
3. invoice.created (relates to customer)

As it stands the event handler for 2 can be executed before 1 and 3 before 2 etc.

What would be the best way to ensure my handlers are executed in the correct order every time? I'm thinking promises of some-sort. If this is the case, what's a good promise module for node?

Comment: node has Promise(), but promises live in ram, and you probably don't want a server reboot to discard the awaiting actions. this is where something like a db trigger is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can reject hook if an event is missing, stripe will try it later but if you want it to happen quick, you can make a small loop waiting for max 10 seconds and who checks every second if missing event is arrived).

I have same problem when updating a billing plan, the event invoice.updated arrives before invoice.created ...

Comment: Yeah I encountered the same problem and I fixed it by rejecting the webhook. But the loop is also a good solution.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil is 10 seconds enough for that?

Comment: @spatak yeah it should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the id of the stripe object as the foreign key on your document? Don't store the actual json object, just the stripe id. When you need to query for the documents, build your result set by using the stripe id as the primary key.