# Azure service hooks: webhooks.... queuing git operations out of order?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So i have a Azure "service hook" webhook configured, but noticing that the git events are "queued" but emit out of order.

What is the ordering of events that are emitted by service hooks?

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/7646

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12552

Comment: If this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775335/stripe-webhooks-events-order?